# How to concatenate two strings with many null characters?

Tags: c, concatenation, memcpy

How to concatenate two strings for example

```
char s[5]={'s','a','\0','c','h'};

char m[11]={'b','e','\0','c','h','b','\0','e','\0','c','h'};
```

that has many null characters. I tried `strcat()`. Its not working. Is there any way?

Comment: techniccally, a null ends a string. use pointer arithmetic and `memcpy()`

Comment: A null-terminated string contains only a single null character, which is obviously the last one in the string.

Comment: There is a `'\0'` missing at the end of your arrays: e.g: `{'s','a','\0','c','h'};` -> `{'s','a','\0','c','h','\0'};`. Without that you cannot determine where the last string ends. Actually you need even two `'\0'`s so you know that there are more strings.

Comment: Better pick one language.

Comment: @Michael: There's many ways to lay out bytes in a buffer, and not all of them involve null-termination. The OP's code is perfectly valid, though perhaps uncommon.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? There's nothing wrong with this question. It could be a little better worded, but that's only because the OP is not completely familiar with the terms/concepts involved (which is normal, otherwise there wouldn't be a need to ask the question in the first place!).

Comment: A C string has **exactly one** `\0` character: at the end. Anything else is not a C string but just an array. How to copy an array can be found by a simple search. What have you done to find out yourself? Why did it not work? What is your **specific** problem? Where is your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is tricky, because by definition C-strings are null-terminated. So what you really have are two byte buffers that you want to put together, not two strings. (This is why functions like `strcat` don't work here, by the way -- they expect their arguments to be C-strings.)

Since you can't use the null character to tell you where the buffer ends as you can with C-strings, you need to know the size of the buffers in advance. Then it's as simple as bit-blitting the two into a single buffer:

```
char dest[16];
memcpy(dest,     s, 5);  // Copy s to the final buffer
memcpy(dest + 5, m, 11); // Copy m to the final buffer just after s
```

Answer (score 1):

All the C standard library string functions will stop on the first `\0`. That's by design. In fact your input arrays will *not* work well with such functions since they don't end with a `\0`.

So the easiest thing for you to do is to use `memcpy` instead, and specify the number of characters to copy yourself. Don't forget to allocate the necessary amount of memory in the destination buffer.

Comment: If they don't stop at the first NUL byte, they are no string functions. That's not a matter of design, but convention/definition of a string in C.

Answer (score 0):

The more straightforward way:

```
const int size_s = 5;
const int size_m = 11;
char s[size_s]={'s','a','\0','c','h'};
char m[size_m]={'b','e','\0','c','h','b','\0','e','\0','c','h'};
char destination[size_s+size_m];
int i;
for (i = 0;i < size_s;i++)
    destination[i] = s[i];

for (i = 0;i < size_m;i++)
    destination[i+size_s] = m[i];
```

Ideally, you should use memcpy

```
const int size_s = 5;
const int size_m = 11;
char s[size_s]={'s','a','\0','c','h'};
char m[size_m]={'b','e','\0','c','h','b','\0','e','\0','c','h'};
char destination[size_s+size_m];

memcpy(destination,s,size_s);
memcpy(destination,m,size_m);
```

Comment: destination + size_s for the second copy?

Answer (score 0):

```
char s[5]={'s','a','\0','c','h'};
char m[11]={'b','e','\0','c','h','b','\0','e','\0','c','h'};
char* e = (char*)malloc(sizeof(s) + sizeof(m));

memcpy(e, s, sizeof(s));
memcpy(&e[sizeof(s)], m, sizeof(m));
```

don't forget to delete the result string when you are done.

```
free(e);
```

Comment: A little cleaner than my answer, but be aware that sizeof on an array is different from sizeof on a pointer (and often when dealing with buffers you won't have the actual array, just a pointer to its first element).

Comment: I know, I was just trying to write as little code as possible. I don't understand why he wants to do this to begin with and even if he had a good reason I would have done it with much more safety than this.

Comment: @SouravGhosh What do you mean?

Comment: Which part of my comment was unclear? :) This question is tagged C, IMHO.

Comment: @SouravGhosh You are correct. I did not pay attention to that. He can use `malloc` and `free` instead of new and delete. But the question was about how to concatenate 2 strings that have null in them. How he creates or deletes the memory is another subject. In any case sorry for the oversight.

Comment: Glad you noticed. So you mind chaging the answer to fit to the tagged language?

Comment: The question used to be tagged C/C++, by the way, hence the confusion. What the OP is actually using is unclear.

Comment: Don't cast `void *` in C!